# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController with editable ABPersonViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I am using an ABPeoplePickerNavigationController to display contacts. When a user selects a contact that contact's info is displayed in what I'm assuming is a ABPersonViewController - this is the behavior that I want. At this point, I would like to be able to edit the contact data by providing an edit button in the righthand side of the ABPeoplePickerNavigationController's navigation bar. Can this be done?

I've tried several things including pushing my own ABPersonViewController onto the navigation controller but even with the 'allowsEditing' flag set and the navigation controller's 'rightBarButtonItem' set to an UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit it wouldn't show the edit button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just set `ABPersonViewController`'s property `allowsEditing` and editing YES. Then you can control the saving action.

Comment: I realize this was a long time ago, but I came a across this question and it seems to be asking exactly what I want to know. I'm not sure, though, how to implement your solution. Can it be done without creating a new `ABPersonViewController` object? For example, if `picker` is an `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController`, is there some property or attribute of it which holds the `ABPersonViewController`, so something like this: `picker. _ .allowsEditing = true` could be done? I already tried `topViewController`, but that didn't seem to work.